# python regex to detect a word exists

Tags: python, regex

I want to detect whether a word is in a sentence using python regex. Also, want to be able to negate it.

```
import re
re.match(r'(?=.*\bfoo\b)', 'bar red foo here')
```

this code works but I do not understand why I need to put `.*` in there.
Also to negate it, I do not know how to do that.
I've tried:

```
re.match(r'(?!=.*\bfoo\b)', 'bar red foo here')
```

but it does not work.
My ultimate goal is to combine them like so:

```
re.match(r'(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?!=.*\bbar\b)', 'bar red foo here')
```

Comment: Why not something like `'foo' in sentence and 'bar' not in sentence`? (Or whatever you're trying to do)

Comment: `re.match(r'\bfoo\b', s) and not re.match(r'\bbar\b', s)`

Comment: Certainly `in` and `not in` are not an option for a whole word search inside a string, that is what regexps are for.

Comment: @L3viathan I can't see where you'd ever prefer that to `'substring' in s`, can you?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: If you have a closer look at the regex, you will notice `\b` - a word boundary. Try emulating it with `in` and `not in`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I'm familiar with that. And that "word boundary" is defined by a word which is [a sequence of Unicode alphanumeric or underscore characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which might be a little surprising.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist No, the *word* is.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's a somewhat common definition of word, but that doesn't matter, what does is what OP wants (as you said). Since their initial regex was looking for words in the regex definition, I chose to keep that. In any case, it works better than `"word" in s`. Only OP can tell us what they prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect if a word exists in  a string you need a *positive lookahead*:

```
(?=.*\bfoo\b)
```

The `.*` is necessary to enable searching farther than just at the string start (`re.match` anchors the search at the string start).

To check if a string has no word in it, use a *negative lookahead*:

```
(?!.*\bbar\b)
 ^^^
```

So, combining them:

```
re.match(r'(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?!.*\bbar\b)', input)
```

will find a match in a string that contains a whole word `foo` and does not contain a whole word `bar`.

Comment: Just an addition: if the string contains newline symbols, compile the regex with a `re.S` (`re.DOTALL`) flag so that `.` could also match a newline, too.

Comment: Matches lines with `bar red foo` in it.

Comment: So Python's match() implies BOS (and not EOS). Well that just put Python on my list of crippled engines.

Comment: No need calling Python names. [Python 3 has a `re.fullmatch` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch).

Comment: I know for sure this regex `(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?!.*\bbar\b)` matches somewhere in this string `bar red foo`. I ran it in Perl but doesn't match in Python, a crippled engine..

Answer (score 2):

***Update***
Just found that Python *re.match()* has an implied `^` anchor.
In other words it will only match at the beginning of the string,
and strangely, unlike Java, does not require it to match the entire string.

Be warned though that combining a sequential positive and negative   **lookahead**,
as in Stribnez answer, can give unintended results if not anchored to
something. Either to literal text or a BOS anchor `^`.

For general usage, don't rely on the fact that (or if), in some language
the *match()* function implies a BOS anchor `^` (and possibly EOS `$`).
Put one (or both) in there at all times. This way it can be used
in *search()* as well. And is portable to other languages.

To see how negative and positive, in-series lookahead's can cause problems,
take this tricky standalone expression `(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?!.*\bbar\b)`

It can be examined like this:

Since it is *in-series*, both assertions have to be matched at the same
position in the string.

Given the same position in the string for both, the negative assertion
can be satisfied when it finds a place that downstream does not match it's contents.

Assuming that no anchoring exists, this leave's an opening *upstream*
(between the search position and the `bar` literal in the example) for
the undesired content to exist, that will still satisfy the positive/negative
assertion pair.

Example:
`(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?!.*\bbar\b)`
*matches*
`bar red foo`

```
**  Grp 0 -  ( pos 1 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

b<here>ar red foo
```

This shows that at position 1, both assertions are satisfied.

Conclusion(s):
1. Always use anchors, even if they are implied.
2. Avoid using any language's match() function, use search() instead.

***End update***

---

It doesn't matter if you use a positive or negative lookahead,
if you don't use the correct syntax, it won't work.

Look at this `(?!=.*\bfoo\b)`

This says that the next character can't be an equal sign `=` followed by
a greedy number of characters up to the next `foo`. This is not allowed.

So, it will not match `= ab foo`, but it will match '=(here) ab foo'.

The next problem is that if you don't give the assertion anything to anchor on
it will use a bump-along to move the postion to a place *between* characters
that will satisfy it.

The corrections for the negative lookahead you are looking for is this
`^(?!.*\bfoo\b)`

---

For reference:

```
(?=..)  Positive lookahead
(?<=..) Positive lookbehind
(?!..)  Negative lookahead
(?<!..) Negative lookbehind
```

And, they can be mixed and nested anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `.*` because `re.match()` tries to match the pattern to the beginning of the string.  If you want to search the whole string, use `re.search()`.

Just as you can do `if re.search(...):`, you can also do `if not re.search(...):`

Comment: Search still returned a match for: re.search(r'(?=\bfoo\b)(?!\bred\b)', 'bar red foo here')  so I guess I cannot use it.