# python regex match a possible word

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a regex to match a word that might not exist. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125179/python-regex-to-detect-a-word-exists) that I should try something like this:

```
import re

line = "a little boy went to the small garden and ate an apple"


res = re.findall("a (little|big) (boy|girl) went to the (?=.*\bsmall\b) garden and ate a(n?)",line)

print res
```

but the output of this is

```
[]
```

which is also the output if I set `line` to be

> a little boy went to the garden and ate an apple

How do I allow for a possible word to exist or not exist in my text and catch it if it exist?

Comment: The question mark quantifier `?` matches zero or one of a given pattern.  the regex `to the (small )?garden` matches both `"to the garden"` and `"to the small garden"` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RDfCYm/1)

Comment: `re.findall(r"a (little|big) (boy|girl) went to the( \bsmall\b){0,1} garden and ate a(n?)", line)` Note the `r` in front of the string.  Without the `r` the backslashes are interpreted.  `'\b'` is the backspace character.  `r'\b'` is a backslash followed by a "b".

Comment: Actually, the `(?=.*\bsmall\b)` lookahead requires the whole word `small` to be present somewhere after the current location, after 0+ chars other than line break symbols. So, it does not have to be `garden`. Still, there must be a consuming pattern, Steven is right. Anyway, the pattern with `\b` must be declared with a raw string literal, or the backslash must be doubled.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:  You are correct.  I missed the `.*`.

Comment: I changed `'the (?=.*\bsmall\b) garden'` to `r'the( \bsmall\b){0,1} garden'`.  Note that your `?=` indicates that the pattern in parenthesis is a lookahead assertion.  Such a pattern does not consume the string when it matches.  That means that `"garden"` will have to be the word after `"the"`.  Instead I changed it to match zero or one times and included a preceding space in the match.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: You may post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to **match** not only a "small" word, but also a space after that (or before that). So you could use regex like this: `(small )?`.
On the other hand you want to **catch** the word only. To exclude the match from capturing you should use regex like this: `(?:(small) )?`

Full example:

```
import re

lines = [
    'a little boy went to the small garden and ate an apple',
    'a little boy went to the garden and ate an apple'
]

for line in lines:
    res = re.findall(r'a (little|big) (boy|girl) went to the (?:(small) )?garden and ate a(n?)', line)
    print res
```

Output:

```
[('little', 'boy', 'small', 'n')]
[('little', 'boy', '', 'n')]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! 

A question: why wouldn't this pattern work ```r'a (little|big) (boy|girl) went to the(?:(small) )?garden and ate a(n?)' ```

Comment: Thanks :) It doesn't work because with this regex you are trying to catch lines like these: `['a little boy went to thesmall garden and ate an apple', 'a little boy went to thegarden and ate an apple']`.
So you miss a space after 'the'.